# Method for variable shortlisting (where sample size is small and variable number is large)

Tags: feature-selection

I have 10 different herb samples, and each sample has ~400 chemical components in varying amounts (all numerical variables). I would like to determine which of these variables contribute to the bioactivity of the sample. The hope is to decrease the number of variables to less than 50.

I have tried principal components analysis but I am unsure about what to do with the data obtained because all the variables are mutually independent.

Stepwise regression seems like a possible solution, but based on the negative reviews of this method it is probably not a good method.

So my question is, what other modern methods are available to decrease the number of variables?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're after? Are you suspecting that some of the chemical components are causal for a certain effect? And are these components present in all plants? On which data did you do your PCA, and why? (Is that relevant to your question?)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to **identify and discard features with high inter-feature-correlation** (see e.g. [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212667/how-do-i-find-co-linear-variables-in-r/213020#213020) for more details and an example in R caret).

You could also utilize classic feature selection approaches, such as **feature filters**, which select features from considering the features itself (e.g. inter-feature-correlation) and the target variable (e.g. feature-target-correlation), without including the model - or **feature wrappers**, which additionally take models into account, hence optimize the resulting model performance instead (see e.g. the [built in feature selection approaches in R caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/featureselection.html)).

In contrast to those purely selective mechanisms you can also utilize **dimensional reduction mechanisms** using PCA to compute PC dimensions, then discarding less important PC dimensions, like you already mentioned. BTW: the [linear independence of PC features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) is caused by how PCA works.